# How to make a Boolean behave like a 'latch'?

Tags: c#, boolean

I initially had the following code:

```
        Boolean successCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean failureCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean timeFound = false;

        foreach (var row in auditRows)
        {
            timeFound = row.Text.Contains(sCurrentTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime2) ? true : false;

            if (timeFound)
            {
                successCheckPoint = row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Success") && !successCheckPoint ? true : false;
                failureCheckPoint = row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Failure") && !failureCheckPoint ? true : false;
            }                                

        }
```

But I found that in later iterations of the foreach, even if the successCheckPoint or failureCheckPoint booleans had been set to true, they'd end up getting set to false because of the way that I'd set up the assignment.

---

Example problem

First Iteration

1. timeFound is true
2. successCheckPoint is false
3. row.Text does contain the text I want
4. successCheckPoint is indeed false
5. successCheckPoint set to true

Second Iteration

1. timeFound is true
2. successCheckPoint is true
3. row.Text does not contain the text I want
4. successCheckPoint is not false
5. successCheckPoint set to false

---

So to fix the problem, I changed the code into this:

```
        Boolean successCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean failureCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean timeFound = false;

        foreach (var row in auditRows)
        {
            timeFound = row.Text.Contains(sCurrentTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime2) ? true : false;

            if (timeFound)
            {
                if (!successCheckPoint)
                {
                    successCheckPoint = row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Success") ? true : false;
                }

                if (!failureCheckPoint)
                {
                    failureCheckPoint = row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Failure") ? true : false;
                }
            }                                

        }
```

This does what I want, but it feels like there should be a better way to go about accomplishing this type of behavior.  Is there any way to set things up so that once a boolean is set to true, it won't get changed back to false for future iterations?

---

Correct Behavior

First Iteration

1. timeFound is true
2. successCheckPoint is false
3. row.Text does contain the text I want
4. successCheckPoint is indeed false
5. successCheckPoint set to true

Second Iteration

1. timeFound is true
2. successCheckPoint is true so skip re-evaluation

---

Sorry if this is still confusing.  I can explain a little bit more if necessary.

---

Edit:  Now that I think about it I don't really need the '? true : false' parts for this code.

New Code:

```
        Boolean successCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean failureCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean timeFound = false;

        foreach (var row in auditRows)
        {
            timeFound = row.Text.Contains(sCurrentTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime2);

            if (timeFound)
            {
                if (!successCheckPoint)
                {
                    successCheckPoint = row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Success");
                }

                if (!failureCheckPoint)
                {
                    failureCheckPoint = row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Failure");
                }
            }                                

        }
```

---

Thanks for the help everyone!  Here's the version of the code I've settled on:

```
        Boolean successCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean failureCheckPoint = false;
        Boolean timeFound = false;

        foreach (var row in auditRows)
        {                            
            if (row.Text.Contains(sCurrentTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime) || row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime2))
            {
                successCheckPoint |= row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Success");
                failureCheckPoint |= row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Failure");
            }

            if (successCheckPoint && failureCheckPoint)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can cut out all of the `var whatever = someBooleanExpression ? true : false` and just write `var whatever = someBooleanExpression`.  The rest is completely redundant.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that right after I submitted.  I've made the proper edit.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not use linq? `rows = auditRows.Where(TimeIsFound); successCheckPoint = rows.Any(RowContainsSuccess); failureCheckPoint = rows.Any(RowContainsFailure);`

Comment: @EdS., you mean I shouldn't be writing `!!(bool == true ? true : false)` to check boolean results?!? how will I be certain they're of the right type?

Comment: @zzzzBov: You forgot the final check; `(!!(bool == true ? true : false)) == true`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [OR assignment operator `|=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx):

```
bool successCheckPoint = false;
bool failureCheckPoint = false;

foreach (var row in auditRows)
{
    if (row.Text.Contains(sCurrentTime) ||
        row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime) ||
        row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime2))
    {
        successCheckPoint |= row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Success");
        failureCheckPoint |= row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Failure");
    }                                
}
```

`a |= b;` is short for `a = a | b;`. So if `a` is already true, it stays true. If `a` is false and `b` is true, then `a` becomes true. Otherwise, `a` remains false.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked just the way I wanted it to, and definitely makes the code look cleaner.  Stackoverflow wants me to wait around 6 minutes before I accept your answer, but this is it!

Answer (score 6):

Just use the OR operator, as in:

```
bool failed = false;

failed |= CheckOne();
failed |= CheckTwo();
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the OR operator!  I'll be marking dtb for the answer, since it ended up cleaning my code some more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really liking the other answers as they're over complicating this code. I feel that linq would help make your code more readable:

```
var rows = auditRows.Where(TimeIsFound);
var successCheckPoint = rows.Any(RowContainsSuccess);
var failureCheckPoint = rows.Any(RowContainsFailure);

...elsewhere...

static bool TimeIsFound(SomeType row)
{
    return row.Text.Contains(sCurrentTime) ||
           row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime) ||
           row.Text.Contains(sLenientTime2);
}
static bool RowContainsSuccess(SomeType row)
{
    return row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Success");
}
static bool RowContainsFailure(SomeType row)
{
    return row.Text.Contains("Web User Login Failure");
}
```

I feel that this would make the code easier to follow, it almost becomes a paragraph:

> Get the rows where some specific times are found. `successCheckPoint` is true if any of the rows contain the success message. `failureCheckPoint` is true if any of the rows contain the failure message.

Making it easy to read helps to make it easier to debug later. Additionally this splits the functionality out into bite-size chunks.

Don't worry about looping multiple times. If you loop once over 100 items and perform 3 actions, it takes approximately the same time as looping 3 times over 100 items and performing 1 action each time (`1 * 100 * 3 == 3 * 100 * 1`, go figure)